# Bundle exec rake spec and custom rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, rake

I have a simple rake task, dedicated for populating my postgresql database (same db for dev, test and prod environments):

```
# lib/tasks.sample_data.rake
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    make_users
    make_user_apps
  end
end

def make_users
 ... users = []; users << User.create(...)
end
........
```

When I use 'bundle exec rake db:populate' this task is working fine. I have full db of User records.

I also have some rspec tests, which are using model User, and a problem with command

```
bundle exec rake spec
```

This command for some reason ruins my db and I have the following result of tests:

```
Failures:

  1) Lead should return counters hash
     Failure/Error: user = User.find(1)
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find User with id=1
     # ./spec/models/lead_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.16812 seconds
```

After this rake task I can see that User.count returns 0

I have default Rakefile and here is the list of all my rake tasks:

```
rake -T

rake about                              # List versions of all Rails frameworks and the environment
rake assets:clean[keep]                 # Remove old compiled assets
rake assets:clobber                     # Remove compiled assets
rake assets:environment                 # Load asset compile environment
rake assets:precompile                  # Compile all the assets named in config.assets.precompile
rake cache_digests:dependencies         # Lookup first-level dependencies for TEMPLATE (like messages/show or comments/_comment.html)
rake cache_digests:nested_dependencies  # Lookup nested dependencies for TEMPLATE (like messages/show or comments/_comment.html)
rake db:create                          # Create the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the current Rails.env (use db:create:all to create all dbs in the config)
rake db:drop                            # Drops the database using DATABASE_URL or the current Rails.env (use db:drop:all to drop all databases)
rake db:fixtures:load                   # Load fixtures into the current environment's database
rake db:migrate                         # Migrate the database (options: VERSION=x, VERBOSE=false, SCOPE=blog)
rake db:migrate:status                  # Display status of migrations
rake db:populate                        # Fill database with sample data
rake db:rollback                        # Rolls the schema back to the previous version (specify steps w/ STEP=n)
rake db:schema:cache:clear              # Clear a db/schema_cache.dump file
rake db:schema:cache:dump               # Create a db/schema_cache.dump file
rake db:schema:dump                     # Create a db/schema.rb file that can be portably used against any DB supported by AR
rake db:schema:load                     # Load a schema.rb file into the database
rake db:seed                            # Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb
rake db:setup                           # Create the database, load the schema, and initialize with the seed data (use db:reset to also drop the db first)
rake db:structure:dump                  # Dump the database structure to db/structure.sql
rake db:version                         # Retrieves the current schema version number
rake doc:app                            # Generate docs for the app -- also available doc:rails, doc:guides (options: TEMPLATE=/rdoc-template.rb, TITLE="Custom Title")
rake log:clear                          # Truncates all *.log files in log/ to zero bytes (specify which logs with LOGS=test,development)
rake middleware                         # Prints out your Rack middleware stack
rake notes                              # Enumerate all annotations (use notes:optimize, :fixme, :todo for focus)
rake notes:custom                       # Enumerate a custom annotation, specify with ANNOTATION=CUSTOM
rake rails:template                     # Applies the template supplied by LOCATION=(/path/to/template) or URL
rake rails:update                       # Update configs and some other initially generated files (or use just update:configs, update:bin, or update:application_controller)
rake routes                             # Print out all defined routes in match order, with names
rake secret                             # Generate a cryptographically secure secret key (this is typically used to generate a secret for cookie sessions)
rake spec                               # Run all specs in spec directory (excluding plugin specs)
rake spec:models                        # Run the code examples in spec/models
rake stats                              # Report code statistics (KLOCs, etc) from the application
rake time:zones:all                     # Displays all time zones, also available: time:zones:us, time:zones:local -- filter with OFFSET parameter, e.g., OFFSET=-6
rake tmp:clear                          # Clear session, cache, and socket files from tmp/ (narrow w/ tmp:sessions:clear, tmp:cache:clear, tmp:sockets:clear)
rake tmp:create                         # Creates tmp directories for sessions, cache, sockets, and pids
```

I am interested why this rake spec ruins my db, because when I am using the same task and 'bundle exec rspec' after that tests are passing.

**UPDATE**
Here is my database.yml:

```
development:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: pgdb
 pool: 15
 username: **************
 password: **************
production:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: pgdb
 pool: 15
 username: **************
 password: **************
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: pgdb
  pool: 15
  username: **************
  password: **************
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have populated `development` DB, and after you have run `rake spec` your `development` DB have been cleared, correct?

Comment: Correct, please consider my database.yml, I have updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some similar issues with my DB getting wiped whenever I would run the unit tests manually with `bundle exec rspec spec`, and it turned out to be that it was using the development environment even though I was setting it manually in `spec_helper.rb` with `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'`.

Now I just explicitly specify `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec spec` or you can put that in a `dotests.sh` script.

See these threads:

[rake cucumber and rake spec always use "develop" environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462906/rake-cucumber-and-rake-spec-always-use-develop-environment)

[Rails 4, New App: Why do tests run in development environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135347/rails-4-new-app-why-do-tests-run-in-development-environment) (I tried the `Rails.env = 'test'` thing and it didn't work for me, but give it a shot)

Comment: Thank you, it works with RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec spec