# Rspec is using my development DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rspec for testing. However, it uses my development DB instead of my test DB. How can this occur?

I simply use rspec to run my tests: `don:my_project_root $ rspec`

It seems like the common mistakes from other questions are only relevant to Rails 3 or are pretty outdated (using commands you no longer use with rspec).

Below is my spec_helper.rb.

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require "capybara/rspec" 
require 'database_cleaner'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
# ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false # commented-out during tim's tutorial

  # Rails cast tutorial
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Have you checked your `database.yml` file to make sure `test` group does  not have `development` database details?  Just cautious :)

Comment: I also noticed that this spec_helper has two blocks for `RSpec.configure do |config|`, one inside of Spork's block, and one that is not.  Is that bad form? Is it ok to just keep the one inside the spork block?

Comment: Thanks @vee - just checked (and added it above). Everything looks okay in there :)

Comment: Yes, recommend just keeping the `RSpec` configuration within `Spork` and removing the outer config.

Comment: The only chance I can think of is that your user has an environment variable `RAILS_ENV` set which has value of `development`.  What environment are you in?

Comment: Move that ENV setting outside and before the `Spork.prefork` block. By the time you get in there, it's too late.

Comment: Also, Spork is such a waste of time. I highly recommend not using it.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Just posted the cleaned up spec_helper. @sevenseacat, how come it's a waste of time? seems to speed up the tests by a ton

Comment: @DonnyP it speeds up your application spinup by caching it; it doesn't speed up the actual time it takes to run your tests. It will also introduce a lot of little bugs when things get cached that shouldn't be, which will waste your time trying to debug. When Rails was a lot slower to boot it was a good idea; nowadays it's simply not necessary.

Comment: @sevenseacat when your app takes 30+ seconds to boot (any app that does something useful), not using preloaders is a pain.

Comment: I find debugging problems caused by the preloader to be more of a pain, and there is yet to be a preloader that doesn't cause such problems.

Comment: Thanks guys, I can look into that more later. In the meantime, my rspec is still using the development db instead of test (the updated spec_helper is above). Any more ideas?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I don't know if any of you is still having the issue, but for me moving

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
```

from `rails_helper.rb` to the top of `spec_helper.rb` fixed it. `spec_helper.rb` does a few things before loading `rails_helper.rb`, and something probably touches the database during that time.

Comment: I saw this on a brand new 4.2 project with generated files (spec_helper/rails_helper).  Hadn't seen this before.  Stepped through it and yeah something in spec_helper is flipping something. Rails.env changes to "development".  You can run everything with `RAILS_ENV` but what @nicolas-mattia said worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and despite having replaced `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'` with `Rails.env = 'test'` in `spec_helper.rb`, I just have to manually specify `RAILS_ENV=test` when I run the command for it to work. Look here, but do try the Rails.env thing first:

[Bundle exec rake spec and custom rake tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403822/bundle-exec-rake-spec-and-custom-rake-tasks/22404863#22404863)

Comment: `$ rspec RAILS_ENV=test` returns an error, what syntax do you use? Also I've logged the environment used while testing, and it is `test`. So I think it's some issue about which db it uses, not necessarily the environment

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake test` is what I use. Your database.yml looks good, not sure where else the DB could be getting flipped.

Comment: why use `bundle exec rake test`? That's not using rspec and when I do that there is no output just this: `my-computer:project (master*) · RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake test
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec spec`, I use rspec on one project and the regular test suite in another.

Answer (score 3):

**Relates to Rails 4.2.1 which is the latest stable version as of this post**

Im still trying to solve this. However as a "stop-gap" you can prepend your rspec commands with an environment declaration "RAILS_ENV=test".

For example: to run a test you would write:

`RAILS_ENV=test rspec path/to/test_spec.rb`

You *could* alias rspec as "RAILS_ENV=test rspec" but that would just be hiding the problem and as such I personally haven't done this ... yet.

Ill be sure to update this thread with a solution as soon as I find one as none of the above as helped me at all.

Comment: This helped me because I had the opposite problem. Was trying to force the env to development on my local machine.  I now use "RAILS_ENV=development rspec scpec"  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I randomly had `$DATABASE_URL` defined in my `.bashrc` file to point directly to my development database. Took me a few hours to find that.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and felt that moving things from `rails_helper.rb` to `spec_helper.rb` wasn't addressing the core issue. Why was rspec loading spec_helper before and/or without `rails_helper.rb`?? Then it dawned on me to check `.rspec` and lo and behold it was improperly set to:

```
--require spec_helper
```

Change that to

```
--require rails_helper
```

and it might just fix your issue without having to move stuff from rails_helper to spec_helper.