# Rails 5: Attempting to create and use new test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, testing

I need to create a new test database (postgres) and am having trouble.  It seems that when I try to run any tests it is attempting to connect to the production database which is worrisome for many reasons.  Here is my database.yml currently.

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: xxxxxx-test
  pool: 5
  username: xxx
  host: localhost
```

But when I run a test I see:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/recipe_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

PG::ConnectionBad:
  FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "IP_ADDRESS", user "PRODUCTION_USER", database "PRODUCTION_DATABASE", SSL off
```

I'm not sure why this is happening or how I am supposed to set this up.

Here's my gemfile for test:

```
group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end
```

It's worth noting that I do not have `database_cleaner` doing anything at the moment.

Comment: Are you using rspec or minitest?

Comment: i am using rspec

Comment: In rails_helper which is automatically generated by rspec, there is line that sets the environment: `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'`. Do you have it?

Comment: yes, I do which is odd

Comment: Let's try do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28086122/2640181

Comment: So to be clear: it is not connecting to the database using the settings under `test:` ? My guess is your `database.yml` is incorrect. Is there only one entry for `test`? (because it will use the last one). Is the indentation of the keys `test, development, production` correct? (they should not be indented at all).

Comment: I agree.  How might I generate a new postgres db for testing and update the `database.yml` to reflect that?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that my `DATABASE_URL` is a remote URL that links to another app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database configuration from `database.yml` is merged with `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]`. But `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` **ALWAYS** takes precedence over the YML configuration. See the Rails [guides on configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database).

The bad news is that you have set `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` to point to your production database which could have been catastrophic.

The good news is that you seem to have a IP whitelist on the production DB that denied your local IP. Otherwise you would be clobbering your production DB!

To fix this you need to determine where `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` is being set and get rid of it. Depending on your setup this can be anywhere from your `~/.profile` to the docker container configuration. Then confirm that you have the correct config:

```
$ rails runner -e test "puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config"
```

This should print something like:

```
{"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"xxxxxx-test"}
```

At this point its safe to create the databases for dev/test with:

```
$ rails db:create
$ rails db:schema:load
```

You can use `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` to let developers use their own local configuration, but you should **NEVER** let it point to the production DB on anything except the actual production server!

Comment: Luckily I had backed up my DB right before doing any of this.  Is there a way to update the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config`?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config` is automatically created by merging `database.yml` with `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]`. You could monkeypatch it but thats really the wrong answer to the wrong question.

Comment: now its showing my test db as the "database".  Is there a way to set this to development as a default?

Comment: If you run `rails runner "puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config"` without the `-e` option it should default to development. The `-e` option sets `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]`.